# How to disable the menu "Run code" and "Run code in terminal"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I've recently downloaded CodeRunner, and for Python, when I click "Run", I get the choice:

[image]

How do I disable it and make it run immediately?

Comment: why use Coderunner, I don't have it and pressing F5 just runs the current python file after creating a launch config

Comment: I also write in other languages thats why I use code runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS Code, the green run button provided by the "Python" extension is to execute the command "`Run Python File in Terminal`". It only requires us to click once to run python files in the Terminal of VS Code:

[image]

For the extension "Code Runner", the run button ("Run Code") provided by it defaults to output results in "OUTPUT". In the previous use, this button will cover the green button provided by the "python" extension, but now that they are integrated, we can choose the execution method.

You could use [F5 to debug](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) the code or try to disable the "Code Runner" extension. (Click "`Enable`" can restore the use of the extension.)

Comment: The thing is I want to disable the drop down menu so it just runs in the terminal

Comment: @Katalysmus -This is the result of the integration of these two extensions. Currently, there is no direct way to just cancel the drop-down menu without disabling one of the extensions.

Comment: Oh ok.Thx. Would it help me uninstalling python and reinstalling the extension?

Comment: @Katalysmus -It does not need and will not uninstall python, you could disable the "Code Runner" extension and then reload VS Code.

Comment: Yes but I also would like to write in different languages without having to change it